# How to revert to a commit moving it to the HEAD and not losing the commit that were after it?

Tags: git

I want to checkout and make a previous commit the new HEAD of my git tree but I want to still retain all the commits that came after it.
so...

Commits: A, B, C, D, E, F
Become: A, B, C, D, E, F, C

Effectively make C the HEAD but keeping E and F.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure what *tree* you want to end up with; and what about commit `D`, did you want to keep that too?  However, commit `C` itself *cannot* appear twice: a commit records its parent, and the parent of `C` is `B`, so the parent of `C` cannot be `F`.  You can make a new commit that is "almost the same as `C`" but has `F` as its parent; but that's a new, different commit.

Comment: basically I want to go back to C and move it to position "G" without loosing the option of using D, E, F. I am fine with this technically being a new commit "G". And I would like to keep this on the same branch if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not really clear on your desired result.  What you have now is (apparently):

```
..- A - B - C - D - E - F   <-- HEAD=somebranch
```

That is, there is a series of commits in the repository, with commit `A` (the `A` stands-in for some big ugly 40-character SHA-1 like `67de23ddb1ed5471e302f6a84fae7a9037a0d980`) having some unspecified parent(s) and a complete tree attached.  If you `git checkout A`, your work-tree is filled with your code (or .txt files or whatever) it stood when commit `A`.  Commit `B` has `A` as its parent, and a complete tree attached, and so on.  You're currently on some branch (which I conveniently called `somebranch`), so the tip of that branch points to commit `F`.  The git-repo-file `HEAD` contains the name of the branch.

If you `git checkout somebranch~3` or `git checkout HEAD~3`, you will find yourself in "detached HEAD" mode, with your work-tree filled with whatever is attached to commit `C`.  This lets you use its contents without doing anything else, and you can later `git checkout somebranch` to go back to being on branch `somebranch` and at commit `F`.

If you like, you can *copy* the tree attached to commit `C` into your work-tree, while being on branch `somebranch` and at commit `F`, then make a new commit `G`.  Here's one way to do it, which assumes you're in the top level of your repository:

```
$ git rm -rf .  # tell git to remove everything on the next
                # commit, but don't commit that yet!
$ git checkout HEAD~3 -- . # tell git to repopulate from C
$ git commit
```

The `git rm` step clears out anything that is in `F` but not in `C`—or rather, clears out *everything*, including the files that *are* in `C`.<sup>1</sup>  Then we extract everything in `C`, into the index/staging-area and work tree, but without changing where `HEAD` points.  Then the `commit` writes the index into a new commit (which we can call `G` or perhaps better, `C'`): its parent is `F` but its *tree*, the set of files that come out when you `git checkout` this commit, is identical to that for `C`.

---

<sup>1</sup>If there's nothing in `C` that's not also in `F`, the `rm` step is unnecessary.  It's also possible to be more clever about what gets done to the work-tree, by finding any files in `F` that are not in `C` and removing only those files, but it's probably not worth much work to optimize this, except as an exercise.  Well, unless you do this very often.

---

There are other ways to get to this point, that give similar or even the same result.  For instance, you can `git revert` commits `D` through `F` (in reverse order), which amounts to applying the reverse of their changes.  (This is why you do it—or git does it—in reverse order: after reverting `F`, which is trivial, undoing whatever was in `E` is also trivial, and so on.  If you try to undo `D` first, though, anything that's gone from the `C`-to-`D` changes as a result of further changes in `E` or `F` will produce a conflict.)  The `git revert` command can do this, either making intermediate commits:

```
git revert HEAD~3..HEAD
```

or skipping them so that you must commit the final result yourself:

```
git revert --no-commit HEAD~3..HEAD
```

The first version gives you several intermediate commits, with the final result being, in effect, commit `C'`; the second gives you the same thing as the `rm, checkout old version, commit`, i.e., just commit `C'`.

---

Finally, there's one more option.  It's not clear why you're keeping `D` through `F`, but one classic reason is that you think they're not quite right, but they might actually be right, or you may want to pluck bits out of them in the future.  So let's say this is the case.  Instead of fussing about with making a new commit `C'` that reverts some of the work, but leaves it in the history, you can simply *rename* this history.  We start by simply adding a new branch name that also points to commit `F`:

```
$ git checkout somebranch  # if not already there
$ git branch savedwork
```

Now we have this:

```
..- A - B - C - D - E - F   <-- HEAD=somebranch, saved-work
```

but let's draw it like this (it's the same drawing, just with a kink in the line):

```
..- A - B - C
              \
                D - E - F   <-- HEAD=somebranch, saved-work
```

and now we can simply `git reset --hard` to make `somebranch` point to commit `C`, and update the work tree to match `C` as well:

```
..- A - B - C               <-- HEAD=somebranch
              \
                D - E - F   <-- saved-work
```

Now we're on branch `somebranch`, which has been "rewound" so that it ends at commit `C`, but the new branch `saved-work` continues to point to commit `F` so that commits `D` through `F` are available if/when needed.

If this is allowed, it's usually the way to go.  The main reason it might not be allowed occurs when you publish your branch-tip to others.  Retracting published commits (by rewinding a branch) makes those other people have to do a bunch of work to recover from that, in some (very common) cases.  If they are OK with doing that work, or there are no such people, rewinding is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the branch with the `--soft` flag to retain the changes

This will move you back from F to C but changes from E and F will be uncommitted

`git reset --soft HEAD@{3}`

So you'll need to commit the changes for E and F after the reset,but  you'll end up with a commit history which looks like this

- Commit A
- Commit B
- Commit C
- Commit D+E+F as single commit

Answer (score 0):

Using a hard reset to set commit C as head of your current branch will effectively do what you want--the to other commits become a "detached head" (however they will be cleaned up eventually as part of garbage collection).  All you need to do to preserve them is make them into a seperate branch:

Let's say your current branch is `master`.  On commit F run:

```
git checkout -b saved-commits // Create the new branch, on commit F
git chekcout master // checkout master again
git reset --hard C // reset the HEAD to commit C (you'll need commit C's hash after the --hard paramter)
```

Now you'll have two branches: `master` (on C) and `saved-commits` (on F).  If you commit again on master it will effectively be commit G.  You can later merge, cherry-pick, or continue to work in the saved-commits branch as well by checking it out (`git checkout saved-commits`)